# Measure CPU usage in Cypress/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, cypress, performance-testing

I recently had an issue in my ReactJS web app that caused severe performance issues. Some component had a bug that caused it to frequently render and cause high CPU usage, over time leading to an unresponsive app. A way to objectively spot the issue was by recording performance in Chrome dev tools. This showed high amounts of time spent in rendering.

Apart from fixing this issue, I'm now looking into a way of detecting such issues by writing a test in Cypress that would detect performance issues like this.

Unfortunately, simply measuring page load times does not show a significant increase. Ideally, I would like to be able to measure CPU usage, or the amount of time the app spends in rendering.

Is there any way to do this in Cypress? Or some other test framework?

Comment: Some links [Using Cypress and Google Lighthouse for Performance Testing](https://applitools.com/blog/using-cypress-google-lighthouse-performance-testing/), [Web Performance Testing With Cypress and Google Lighthouse](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/using-cypress-google-lighthouse-performance-testing/), [Cypress Lighthouse Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-lighthouse).

Comment: I wonder though is there a way to catch the render count in Cypress. Maybe add a counter to the `window.Cypress` object at the top of the suspect component, then run an expectation on it after a time period.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something more low-level, but integrating lighthouse may also be worth investigating. I could benchmark it for the current performance and have the test fail if it degrades.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of stuff irrelevant to your issue. I would start with a simple render counter.

Comment: The problem is that the issue is in a library, not in a component I directly control. I can also hardly put render counters in every single component. Also, I'm not so much interested in detecting this specific issue, but being able to spot similar issues in the future.

Comment: Ok, I got a different impression from the question, looked like you were after a regression test.

Comment: CPU sounds like a shifting target. And I would presume the library dependency point can be identified from it's import, which is where I'd put the render counter. With the level of info you give, the answer is speculation.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a regression test. I think it would be good to somehow be able to measure CPU Usage, then put that as a threshold to make sure app versions that cause higher CPU Usage are rejected. But Lighthouse looks promising for this actually, and probably measures a lot more than just CPU. I can set a specific performance score based and reject app versions that perform worse.

Comment: So you'll always measure CPU on the same hardware? Not going to put it in CI?

Comment: It will run on Fargate actually. I expect the CPU capacity to be constant.